# What are values prepended to column names in an SQL query?

Tags: java, sql

This may be a very stupid question, but I'm working on repurposing some code.  I'm not an SQL guy.  In this code:

`select a1.email_id from v_account_email a1`

What is the a1?  What does it do?

Comment: It's a shortcut for the table `v_account_email`, nothing else.

Comment: Next time, search around. There are a lot of resources available that can answer this question. https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+basics

Comment: Hey JSuar - call me stupid, but if you don't know to search for "Alias" I walked through several SQL tutorials and searched and searched for hours and didn't get the answer.  Now that someone said Alias it is easy to find everything I need about how to create and use them.  I did say it might be a very stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a1` is an alias to table `v_account_email`

it is defined in the last half of the sql

```
 from v_acount_email a1
```

it is just a short way to refer to the table.

Answer (score 1):

It's an alias for the table v_account_email, which has a long name, so you can save typing in the rest of the query.

Answer (score 1):

`a1` is an alias for `v_account_email`, which means that you can reference that table instance as `a1` thereafter.

Useful for

- general laziness
- multiple references to the same table in a select if, for some reason, you need to join the table with itself.